# How can I store the content of a *.css file (text file) with addidional information in a new file?

Tags: c++, css, file, c++11, qfile

I have a textfile (*.css Cascading Style Sheets) file, which is a plain text.

Then I have additional program information, just some double and int values, which has noithing to do with the text file directly.

I would like to store that state in a file, so that when I open that file I have access to the content of the *.css and the double and int values. 
So I would be able the applications last state with the text file content and those double and int values.

What would be the most effective way?

Comment: Maybe using import - https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. How does CSS relate to C++ here? Are you trying to create a CSS file that has C++ variables in it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you'll want the result to still be usable as a CSS File. In that case, add a comment block with a marker at the beginning, where you can store your data in some ASCII-Format, e.g. JSON. Like e.g.:

```
/* --@-- 
  {x=42, y=47.11, whatever="blabla"}
*/

/* here comes the original css */
```

Then you can easily find out, if the data is already there by looking for  `/* --@--`. You can use existing JSON parsers to retrieve your data and existing JSON writers to generate the file. You don't have to parse the whole CSS, but only the comments with the marker.